# Name or link to the instrumental that plays at 11:47 - 14:58 in Tokyo Ghoul season 2 episode 11?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

Beautiful melody that starts of soft then raises in intensity and balances out. Perfect fit for the scenes

Comment: Did you not find it in the soundtrack?

Answer (score 1):

It is titled 'Licht und Schatten' by Yutaka Yamada [(Disc 1, Track #25)](http://vgmdb.net/album/50263).